# What were the $r$ and $n$ of $\theta$s (Polchinski String theory section 8.6 page 265)?

Tags: string-theory, group-theory, definition, notation, symmetry-breaking

In the Polchinski String theory section 8.6 page 265

> In generic backgrounds, all the $\theta$s are distinct and the only massless vectors are the diagonal ones, $i = j$. The unbroken gauge group in this case is $U(1)^n$. If $r$ of the $\theta$s are equal, the corresponding $r \times r$ matrix of
> vectors is massless, carrying the gauge symmetry $U(r)$. With the $n$ $\theta$s equal in sets of $r_i$, the gauge symmetry is
> $$U(r_1) \times ... \times U(r_s) ,\qquad \sum_{i=1}^s r_i = n. \tag{8.6.12}$$

What did the factor $r$ mean? One thought they were radius, but the different $\theta_n$ arise from the Chan-Patton states $|ij\rangle$ of the open strings, not a different theory. From the context, $r$ was required to be an integer. The factor $n$ was also confusing, shouldn't it be twice the number of the open string? Why $\sum_{i=1}^s r_i = n$?

Comment: $r$ is a number. Like, try substituting “3” for $r$ and reread the passage and it’ll make more sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The numbers $r_i\in\mathbb{N}$ are the degeneracies/multiplicies of the eigenvalues $\theta_i$ of the diagonal background gauge field $A_{25}$ in the compactified 25th direction
$$ A_{25}~=~-\frac{1}{2\pi R}{\rm diag}(\theta_1,\ldots,\theta_n)~\in~u(n).\tag{8.6.8}$$
The numbers $r_i$ become the [ranks of the Lie Group](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/rank+of+a+Lie+group) factors $U(r_i)$ of the unbroken gauge group (8.6.12).